# How to add g:Vertex GraphSON in Python Gremlin?

Tags: python, json, gremlin, gremlin-server, graphson

I put the [example vertex GraphSON](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.6/dev/io/#_vertex_2) of a `g:Vertex` in a file:

```
$ cat vertex.json 
{ "@type" : "g:Vertex", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 1 }, "label" : "person", "properties" : { "name" : [ { "@type" : "g:VertexProperty", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int64", "@value" : 0 }, "value" : "marko", "label" : "name" } } ], "location" : [ { "@type" : "g:VertexProperty", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int64", "@value" : 6 }, "value" : "san diego", "label" : "location", "properties" : { "startTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 1997 }, "endTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2001 } } } }, { "@type" : "g:VertexProperty", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int64", "@value" : 7 }, "value" : "santa cruz", "label" : "location", "properties" : { "startTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2001 }, "endTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2004 } } } }, { "@type" : "g:VertexProperty", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int64", "@value" : 8 }, "value" : "brussels", "label" : "location", "properties" : { "startTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2004 }, "endTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2005 } } } }, { "@type" : "g:VertexProperty", "@value" : { "id" : { "@type" : "g:Int64", "@value" : 9 }, "value" : "santa fe", "label" : "location", "properties" : { "startTime" : { "@type" : "g:Int32", "@value" : 2005 } } } } ] } } }
```

Trying to read it into Python Gremlin Server:

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal 
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection 

g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g')) 
g.io("/home/ubuntu/vertex.json").read().iterate()
```

yields an error:

> GremlinServerError: 500:
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Could not deserialize the JSON value as required. Nested exception:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: Cannot deserialize the value with
>   the detected type contained in the JSON ('g:Vertex') to the type
>   specified in parameter to the object mapper (interface java.util.Map).
>   Those types are incompatible.  at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream);
>   line: 1, column: 36]

I've tried messing with the `graphson_reader` and `message_serializer` parameters of `DriverRemoteConnection` to specify `GraphSONSerializersV3d0` but I can't get past that error.

How can the example vertex GraphSON above be read into a graph from Python's Gremlin Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you create the GraphSON? It might be worth using TinkerGraph to create a simple GraphSON file and comparing yours to that to make sure you have the syntax correct. I used the steps below to create the JSON also shown below. The GraphSON in your example looks more like a query result than a file describing a graph. Anyway here is an example:

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('name','some-name').property('age','some-age')
==>v[61015]
gremlin> g.io('test.json').write()   

{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":61015},"label":"test","properties":{"name":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":61016},"value":"some-name"}],"age":[{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":61017},"value":"some-age"}]}}
```

Here is a link to the Apache TinkerPop GraphSON reference documentation.

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.6/dev/io/#graphson

Comment: Oh no, are you saying my input isn't Graphson?  FWIW, the link sourcing my input and the link you reference are the same, except I'm pointing to [this block](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.6/dev/io/#_vertex_2), which I thought was an example of a properly formatted GraphSON2 vertex.  If that's not right, could you clarify what that block is and whether there is a way to load it?

Comment: What you showed is the JSON that you might get from running a query. If you read the documentation it shows examples similar to the one I posted in the answer that show the file format for loading a graph. Notice the differences such as there is no g:Vertex, just the "id" etc. I suggest you do what I did and save a vertex from TinkerGraph and study the output.